# Typescript not detecting type mismach

Tags: typescript

I have function `findFlightRecommendation` function. It returns `Flight` type.

```
export const findFlightRecommendation = <T>(state: IStore, sectorIds: T): Flight => {
  if (!state || !state.search || !state.search.results) {
    return undefined
  }
  ...
  return state.search.results.find(r => _.isEqual(r.sectorsId, sectorIds))
}
```

This function is used for find flight:

```
// state.personalData.sectorsKey is string[]
const flight = findFlightRecommendation(state, state.personalData.sectorsKey)
```

Later this `flight` object is used on other function as the param.

```
formatLoadingSubtitle(props.t, flight, getTravellers(state.form.searchForm.values)
```

But `formatLoadingSubtitle` types declaration says that flight should be as `HasSectors`:

```
export const formatLoadingSubtitle = (t: Translate, flight: HasSectors, travellers: number) => {
  const departure = getDepartureTime(flight)
  const arrival = getReturnTime(flight)

  if (departure) {
    return formatFlightDetails(t, departure, arrival, travellers)
  }
}
```

Types:

```
export interface Flight extends BasicFlightInfo {
  mtk?: boolean
  sectorsId?: string[]
  sectorCodes?: string[]
  handBaggage?: IHandBaggage
  checkedBaggageIncluded?: boolean
  leftSeats?: number
  topRecommendationTag?: FilterSortByTypes
  recommendationPriority?: number
}

export interface BasicFlightInfo extends HasSectors, FlightDebugInfo {
  totalPrice: number
  paxPrices: IPaxPrices
  currency: string
  offerFees: IOfferFees
  totalDiscount?: number
  cabinClasses?: string[]
}

interface HasSectors {
  sectors: ISector[]
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `state.personalData.sectorsKey` ?

Comment: `sectorsKey: string[] `

Comment: `Flight` extends `BasicFlightInfo` which extends `HasSectors`. Typescript will let you pass in a derived object where a base type is expected (this is basic OOP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue, as every object implementing `Flight` interface also implements `HasSectors` by inheritance through `BasicFlightInfo`.

It means that anytime a `HasSectors` is expected, anything implementing it (i.e. any object implementing `HasSectors`, `BasicFlightInfo` or `Flight`) can be used.

Everything is working as intended, there is no "Type mismatch".